# Spring Boot @Autowired by generic not work for @InjectMocks

Tags: spring, spring-test, spring-annotations

We know that the main advantage of @Autowired is not hardcoding the concrete implementation. Look at my Code:

```
public interface GeneralDao<T> {
    T get(Long id);
}

@Component
public class BarDao implements GeneralDao<Bar> {
    @Override
    public Bar get(Long id) {
        Bar bar = new Bar(); // hardcode
        bar.setId(id);
        return bar;
    }
}

public interface GeneralService<T> {
    T get(Long id);
}

@Service
public class BarService implements GeneralService<Bar> {
    @Autowired
    private GeneralDao<Bar> barDao;

    @Override
    public Bar get(Long id) {
        return barDao.get(id);
    }
}
```

And now i'm trying to write a test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BarServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private GeneralDao<Bar> barDao;

    @InjectMocks
    private GeneralService<Bar> barService;

    @Test
    public void get() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setId(1L);
        when(barDao.get(1L)).thenReturn(bar);

        Bar actualBar = barService.get(1L);
        assertThat(actualBar, equalTo(bar));
    }
}
```

But it does not work! 
why when do I write:

```
@InjectMocks private GeneralService<Bar> barService;
```

show me exception? By still work for:

```
@Mock private GeneralDao<Bar> barDao
```

I do not want to write like this:

```
@InjectMocks private BarService barService;
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you have to inject a specific implementation. You have to test it with a specific class, not the generic one.

Comment: @sebadagostino but I don't want to write a specific implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have to test the `BarService` you can do it by specifying the implementation class as below.

```
@InjectMocks private GeneralService<Bar> barService = new BarService(barDao);
```